# JavaFX/FXML is it possible to show a Hbox/VBox after clicking a MenuButton

Tags: java

I recently started coding in FXML/JavaFX using Eclipse and one of the projects I'm working on requires me to make a drop down menu with combobox, checkboxes etc.. So my question is would it be possible to make the MenuButton display a VBox/HBox when clicked with those inside?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one of the simplest example of menu:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Menu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MenuFX extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Group group = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(group, 800, 600);
        MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
        Menu someValues = new Menu("Values");

        for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
            MenuItem item = new MenuItem("Value " + i);
            someValues.getItems().add(item);
        }

        menuBar.getMenus().add(someValues);
        group.getChildren().addAll(menuBar);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

More expanding example [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/JavaFX/0560__JavaFX_Menu.htm).

Comment: This works yes but is there a way I could do this in fxml/scene builder instead?